# Converting from PyTorch to Tensorflow for Self-Attention Pooling Layer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model, code-translation

I have found an implementation of the said layer from this paper, "Self-Attention Encoding and Pooling for Speaker Recognition", available at [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.01077) via Pytorch. However, due to CUDA compatibility issues, I can't want to use the said code. Also, thus far, all my codes have been implemented in Tensorflow. So, I want to do a one-to-one translation/conversion or whatever, from PyTorch to Tensorflow.

First of all, this is the code in PyTorch:

```
class SelfAttentionPooling(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(SelfAttentionPooling, self).__init__()
        self.W = nn.Linear(input_dim, 1)
    
    def forward(self, batch_rep):
        """
        input:
            batch_rep : size (N, T, H), N: batch size, T: sequence length, H: Hidden dimension
      
        attention_weight:
            att_w : size (N, T, 1)
    
        return:
            utter_rep: size (N, H)
        """
        softmax = nn.functional.softmax
        att_w = softmax(self.W(batch_rep).squeeze(-1)).unsqueeze(-1)
        utter_rep = torch.sum(batch_rep * att_w, dim=1)

        return utter_rep
```

And this is my translation of the snippet code to Tensorflow:

```
class Self_Attention_Pooling(keras.layers.Layer): ?
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(Self_Attention_Pooling, self).__init__()

        self.W = Dense(input_dim)

    def forward(self, batch_rep):
        softmax = Softmax()
        att_w = self.W(batch_rep)
        att_w = softmax(att_w)
        
        # Not so sure about these two lines though.
        #x = np.expand(batch_rep)
        #att_w = softmax(self.W(x))

        utter_rep = np.sum(batch_rep * att_w, axis=1)

        return utter_rep
```

Is my implementation/translation/conversion from PyTorch to Tensorflow correct? If not, please edit and help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

2 remarks regarding your implementation:

- For custom layers in TF, you should implement the `call` method instead of  the `forward` method cf [Implementing custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers#implementing_custom_layers).
- For the operations you should replace the `numpy` functions by `tensorflow` functions to enable GPU support.

---

Here is the code I am using in TF for the `SelfAttentionPooling`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class SelfAttentionPooling(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, use_bias=False)
    
    def call(self, x: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
        """Apply the self attention pooling on input tensor.
        
        Args:
            x: input tensor (?, seq_len, emb_dim)
        
        Returns:
            (?, emb_dim)
        """
        # (?, seq_len)
        attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(tf.squeeze(self.dense(x)))
        
        # (?, emb_dim)
        pooled = tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(attention_weights, axis=-1) * x, axis=1)

        return pooled
```

You can quickly check it gives the expected output:

```py
self_attn_pooling = SelfAttentionPooling()
# (?, seq_len, emb_dim)
input_shape = 4, 9, 128
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)

pooled = self_attn_pooling(x)

# (?, emb_dim)
assert pooled.shape == (4, 128)
```